# return BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, exception, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

Good Night, why my return "dollar", is coming return "BeautifulSoup AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'", what am I doing wrong? I want to bring the dollar quote in this code

```
import
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as url

 site = "https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/"
       try:
           url2 = site
           con = url.urlopen(url2, None, 7) 

           if con.status == 200:
               HTML = con.read() 

               soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'html.parser')  

               dolar = re.search(r'Cotacao do Dolar: ',
                                       str(soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'subtituloGrafico subtituloGraficoValor'})))  
               return dolar

       except Exception as e:

           if str(e) == 'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND':
               return 'Error'

           return str(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pythonista said *because nothing in the soup was found*. I try to search what you need by class in browser, then i found that `class="subtituloGrafico subtituloGraficoValor"`  belongs to `<a>`. So i understand what you may desire to get.

Note: `soup.find("h3",{"class":"tituloGrafico"})` is used to narrow your search

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as url
import re

site = "https://economia.uol.com.br/cotacoes/"
def func(site=site):
        try:
            url2 = site
            con = url.urlopen(url2, None, 7) 
            if con.status == 200:
                HTML = con.read() 
                soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')
                sub = soup.find("h3",{"class":"tituloGrafico"})
                title = sub.findChild("a").text
                dolar = sub.find('a', attrs={'class': "subtituloGrafico subtituloGraficoValor"}).text
                print(title,dolar)
                #dolar = re.search(r'Cotacao do Dolar:(.*?)',text)
                return dolar
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            if str(e) == 'HTTP Error 404: NOT FOUND':
                return 'Error'
            return str(e)
func()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. This:

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'subtituloGrafico subtituloGraficoValor'})
```

Is returning None because nothing in the soup was found. Make sure you're actually searching this correctly it's not created dynamically etcetera.

You can also search by text and extract it using BS without explicitly using re.

Comment: Thank you for answering